# Vuejs two way binding array

Tags: vuejs2

I have this data:
Sample = [1,2,3]

one input, and and two button

The button are next data and previous

So the idea is to two way bind the input to Sample[var], where var is changeable via the button,

I've been trying to use compute setter or bind the array with changeable var in the data, with no success, what approach should I take?

here's the code:

```
<ckeditor v-model="thedata"></ckeditor>

data() {
    return {
        Sample: [1,2,3],
        thedata: Sample[var],
        var : 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<ckeditor v-model="sample[index]"></ckeditor>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        sample: [1,2,3],
        index: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I simplify it by moving the calculation to computed property?

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to help you. So, you want the value of thedata is based on Sample and var, right?

You can try this code :

```
<template>
  <input v-model="thedata" type="text" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Sample: [1, 2, 3],
      var: 0,
      thedata: '',
    };
  },
 
  mounted() {
    this.thedata = this.Sample[this.var];
  },
};
</script>
```

You can useY `mounted()` and then combine the data.